# How do you made Google Cloud Functions only worked when pinged from certain URLS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions

I made a Google Cloud function, but it returns data even when I type in the URL in an incognito window. How do I make my Google Cloud functions only available for myWebsite.com or localhost?

Comment: Check the request headers, although anything can be spoofed.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible to fully enforce.  When you make an HTTP endpoint, you should expect that it could be accessed from anywhere, and that the access may have headers that do not match what a web browser would normally send.

Comment: Aren't cloud functions used to read/write databases? Where is the security? Just hope no one figures out your Cloud Function endpoints?

Comment: You can require that only Firebase authenticated users can access your endpoint, but you have to write some code in the function itself.  Or use new "callable" functions.

Comment: What if I'm not using Firebase or any other kind of account managing service? (I'm trying to build a website that fetches data from a Google Sheet)

Comment: Then you can expect that your function can be invoked from anywhere by anyone with an internet connection.  What you're asking is common for all endpoint hosting services.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/229859/how-to-avoid-unauthorized-use-of-an-api

Comment: Interesting. It's odd why URL restriction for Cloud Functions isn't implemented given that you can with a regular Node server and cors https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuring-cors

Comment: If cors meets your needs, then use it with Cloud Functions.

Comment: I don't think that's possible because cors is for servers, not cloud functions?

Comment: So I can't use cors

Comment: There are many examples of using cors with Cloud Functions, so use that if it meets your needs.  But it won't stop anyone with an internet connection from directly invoking your HTTP endpoint hosted by Cloud Functions.